# inflated view is null

Tags: android, inflate, viewgroup

I tried to create custom **ViewGroup** class, but when I used method **findViewById()** it returns null, but inflating the view is ok.

code is:

```
public class HorizontalListView extends ViewGroup 
{
    private int mNumber = 0;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private LinearLayout mAdapter;

    public HorizontalListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet set)
    {
        super(context, set);
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_horizontal_list_view, this, false);

        mAdapter = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
    }

    /**Adds ImageView to LinearLayout (Adapter)
     * g
     * @param image
     */
    public void addView(final Bitmap image)
    {
        mImage = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                                    .inflate(R.layout.create_added_photo, null);
        mImage.setImageBitmap(image);
        mImage.setTag(mNumber);
        mNumber++;
        mAdapter.addView(mImage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

here **mAdapter.addView(mImage);** I have a NullPointerException

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list_for_new_photos">

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Check that `mAdapter` isn't null

Comment: You're not catching the inflated view.  You're just inflating it and letting the GC collect it.  Set the last parameter to "true" to attach the inflated view to your current view.

Comment: According to your example `getChildAt(0)` returns the `HorizontalScrollView` and not the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
public HorizontalListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_horizontal_list_view, this, false);
    mAdapter = (LinearLayout) view.getChildAt(0);
}
```

or

```
public HorizontalListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_horizontal_list_view, this, false);
    mAdapter = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.list_for_new_photos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mAdapter might not be instantiated in HorizontalListView with the `getChildAt(0);` line.

There you should check if mAdapter is null, and then if that is unacceptable, instantiate it to something else.

If it's OK for mAdapter to be null, then lower down you'll have to ask if mAdapter is null before you go adding views to it.  You can't add views to a null mAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the layout xml file in both "land" and "layout" folders.